# stdin not reading last line of input

Tags: c++

So I have a program like so:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int x) {
    int result = 1;
    for(x; x > 1; --x) {
         result*=x;
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    // your code goes here
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        std::cout<< "\n";
        std::cout << "entering for loop ";
        int x;
        std::cin >> x;
        std::cout << "entering fac ";
        std::cout << factorial(x);
        std::cout << "leaving fac ";
        std::cout << "leaving for loop ";
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run the program instead of giving the input one at a time I input all of it in all at once into terminal. On giving it input like so:

4

1

2

5

3

The program outputs:

entering for loop entering fac 1leaving fac leaving for loop

entering for loop entering fac 2leaving fac leaving for loop

entering for loop entering fac 120leaving fac leaving for loop

entering for loop

As you see it is not receiving the last value from stdin. Why is this happening, can someone explain?

Comment: Are you sure that `factorial` is not in an infinite loop

Comment: @EdHeal -- that doesn't seem likely, since it works the first three times it's called.

Comment: Reproduce I cannot.

Comment: What did you type after that final "3"?

Comment: factorial outputs the correct values for the first 3 values. The values of factorial(1), factorial(2) and factorial(5) are outputted as 1, 2 and 120 so it seems to be working for those. In theory its just decrementing a number until it reaches 1 and multiplying by a result value.

Comment: @PeteBecker I didnt type anything after the final 3. I basically just copy pasted exactly that as input and pasted it into the terminal for stdin

Comment: Hmmm. Reproduced by not pasting in the enter after that last 3

Comment: Put `std::flush`  at the end of each `cout`

Comment: @user4581301 yes thank you i was missing that last enter, how stupid of me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely to have forgotten the last new line.

If you don't press the enter key at the end, the code is still waiting on this line:

```
std::cin >> x;
```